# Xdebug can debug codeception but not codeception tests

Tags: symfony, xdebug, codeception

I am running Codeception tests in a Symfony2 project and I am developing in PHPstorm.

Debugging codeception used to work, but i recently started a new project it doesn't anymore. Everything is configured as it should. When I set phpstorm to start listening for connections, and I set a breakpoint in bin/codecept. The debugger halts at the breakpoint (as it should).

But when I set the breakpoint in a test (which is definetly ran), I get the message

```
16:10:41 Debug session was finished without being paused
         It may be caused by path mappings misconfiguration or not synchronized local and remote projects.
         To figure out the problem check path mappings configuration for 'null' server at PHP|Servers or enable Break at first line in PHP scripts option (from Run menu).
         Do not show again (show balloon)
```

I do believe that something is going wrong with the path mapping, because my server is running on a symlink, but why does debugging app/console and codeception itself work, but not the tests ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of this:

https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/1636#issuecomment-71205765

> test is not executed directly, it is triggered from reflection.

Comment: I can only suggest a workaround - put a breakpoint in the helper method that you want to debug.

Comment: That does work, which allready helps me alot! so strange that the tests themselves don't get hit.

Comment: OMG! I found the problem. I renamed my tests folder to Tests, And I saw this in my code ```/Library/WebServer/Documents//src/AppBundle/tests/unit/Form/MenteeTypeTest.php```
so the folder names are for some reason out of sync. Thank you so much